# Best efficient method to get SQL Server data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlclient

I would like to know what custom code (not EF) the experts use to get data from SQL Server in .NET / C#. I have been using methods like this:

```
public static DataTable SelectAllForNavigation()
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnStr))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spr_Web_Content", sqlConn);
            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Op", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "SelectAllForNavigation";

            SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(sqlDr);
            sqlDr.Close();
            sqlDr.Dispose();
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It works and I don't see an overhead in SQL Server when hammering requests for data, but recently I have modified the method to this:

```
public static DataTable SelectAllForNavigation()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spr_Web_Content", sqlConn))
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Op", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "SelectAllForNavigation";
                sqlConn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(sqlDr);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Similar, but with 2 major differences; using `using` wrappers and placed a `try/catch` around the whole thing to try to catch any potential connection issues as well.

My questions are:

1. Is this new method that much better from an efficient perspective?
2. Where should the `sqlConn.Open()` be placed in the code?
3. Do I still need the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` in the `SqlDataReader` now that its wrapped with a `using`?
4. Any better way to do this, efficiently?

Comment: I am using SQLHelper library. It is very useful, check it out. Microsoft.ApplicationsBlock.data.dll i think it's the assembly.

Comment: If you're going to use ADO.NET, then I'd suggest loading lightweight Plain Old CLR Objects (POCOs) as a strongly typed domain model rather than DataTables. That would reduce the apps memory footprint at least. It also provides you the benefit of having a real domain model. However, this is only useful if you make use of the domain model and don't rely on the inbuilt features of a DataTable

Comment: On some instances I'm using a `DataTable` for just 1 row (never gets more than 1 row), will it save memory if I use a `DataRow` for these cases?

Comment: @Nelson Yes it would likely save memory using a POCO above and beyond a DataTable. Having said that though, I should qualify my previous statement. While it may well be more efficient in terms of memory use, it will add overhead in the code you need to write. Like everything else, there is a tradeoff in every choice you make. You need to understand the tradeoffs and work out if they are acceptable in your situation. For smallish apps, it may well be that DataTables are just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to use `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable`. In this you don't need to `Open` and `Close` connection explicitly.

Also in your current approach you are getting data in `SqlDatareader` and than loading in `DataTable` so you are creating an extra object which will occupy memory.

Using `SqlDataAdadpter` approach is called `Disconnected` or `ConnectionLess` while using `SqlDataReader` is called `Connection Oriented` approach.

Difference is that in `ConnectinoOriented` approach you need to `Open` and `Close` connection manually also connection should remain `open` until you are reading data. In other approach you can read data even `connection` is `closed`.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from testtable where id=@id", con));
   {
   adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
   adapter.Fill(dt);
   }         
}
```

Comment: I am reading the `SqlDataReader` is much faster and as a smaller memory footprint in relation to the `SqlDataAdapter`. Memory is at a premium on my VPS host so this is a top consideration. I usually just get data, populate a string, bool or datatable and return that. For `DataTable` populating it with a `SqlDataReader` or `SqlDataAdapter` will have the same cost in memory, but maybe the `SqlDataReader` is faster, your insights on this please. Also, in your example, cant we wrap the `SqlDataAdapter` in a `using` also?

Comment: Yes you are right `SqlDataReader` is much faster but it keeps the connection open if you read data through `SqlDataReader`. So it will take some resources until you are fininshed with `SqlDataReader`. Yes we can wrap the `SqlDataAdadpter` in `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is this new method that much better from an efficient perspective?*

No, in terms of performance, the two approaches are probably almost identical. But your "new", second approach is much better in terms of **maintainability** and safety - it ensures that objects like `SqlCommand` etc. are freed as soon as possible.

> *Where should the sqlConn.Open() be placed in the code?*

Just before you execute the query is really the best place for this - the connection really doesn't need to be open while you're doing all your setup work ....

> *Do I still need the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection in the SqlDataReader now that its wrapped with a using?*

It's still a good idea, yes - even if the `using` block will also close the connection (when disposing the `SqlCommand`), I always find doing so explicitly in my own code is even better (and certainly doesn't hurt).

> *Any better way to do this, efficiently?*

In terms of developer productivity : use Entity Framework to get rid of having to write all that gooey code - but if you insist on using low-level ADO.NET, that's about as good as it gets.

Comment: as far as performance is concerned, native code is always the best opiton.

Comment: Thanks guys, there's still a few optimizations to be done, but getting there.

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin: so you write all your programs in assembler code then??

Answer (score 1):

> Is this new method that much better from an efficient perspective?

I don't think so. As far as I see, only difference between your methods is using of `using` statement and this method does not make your method more efficient. It provides an auto mechanism disposing for [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects.

> Where should the sqlConn.Open() be placed in the code?

Just before when you need an open connection. In your fist case, I would use it just before `SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` line since I only *need* first time to an open connection.

> Do I still need the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection in the
>   SqlDataReader now that its wrapped with a using?

It is still a better approach to use it. For example, if your code throws an exception on it and if you don't use `CloseConnection`, your code won't access the contents of your reader. Also, using `CloseConnection` *may* harm your code little bit [based on this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/technopeak/IPEMDs9K8U8).

> Any better way to do this, efficiently?

That depends a lot of things but if you use them in small project, ADO.NET will be efficient as well but I *generally* use EF as much as I can.

Comment: Nice to have your insights and the `CloseConnection` on the `SqlDataReader` seems to have a problem as your reference post shows, nice to know this and I think the connection is closed without this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I read in ur description, that u hammer in requests. So I assume u talk about alot of frequent requests. If this occurs, i highly recommend to not close ur sql connection after each query. This will speed up ur method actually a lot, because ur application doesn't need to communicate, handshake, and ... for every single query.

> Is this new method that much better from an efficient perspective?

Using is actually nothing to do with performance. It's actually a helper for the developer, and to keep the Garbage Collection cleaner. Using does nothing else then calling the `Object.Dispose()` as using needs an `IDisposable` Object to work. So u don't have to deal with closing and disposing the connection. So performance grant equals to zero.

> Where should the `sqlConn.Open()` be placed in the code?

If u keep in mind my first answer, u should establish the connection somewhere in the loading of ur window.

> Do I still need the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection in the SqlDataReader now that its wrapped with a using?

No. If ur interested in what is using doing [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> Any better way to do this, efficiently?

See my first post. The rest of the actual query can't be boosted, because it's actually just building the query, and sending it to the server and finally retreiving it.

Comment: Good point about opening 1 connection for all the queries. I'll have to consider a change in architecture to accommodate that, but isn't ADO.NET smart enough to actually do this already? Seems logical and saves all the handshakes.

Comment: ADO.net is a Framework like .NET or anything else. If u tell it to close and dispose a connection it will be closed and disposed. Regardless of any further use, ur next use will need to open it again. And that's what using is doing. Calling Dispose, which will call a Close.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm settling for this solution:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnStr))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spr_Web_Content", sqlConn))
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Op", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "SelectAllForNavigation";

        sqlConn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sqlDr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(sqlDr);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

It seems to provide the best performance and efficiency. I just have a couple more doubts before I wrap this topic and move on;

1. Do I save memory be returning a `DataRow` as opposed to a `DataTable` with 1 row?
2. I keep seeing `using (var sqlConn = ...` is this same as `using (SqlConnection sqlConn = ...`?

Thanks.